# How to customize swagger ui page - the context panel

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

we use the default swagger ui css. Right now, I am facing an issue that the context panel is not wide enough. So when we have a long word (concated word) in the description, the data type column is pushed out of the panel. I changed the screen.css file but how to make it effect? Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After `gradle build` the project, the css changes take effect. Note that it needs to clear cache and load the page.